# How to POST specific parameters and their value via http protocol in C#?

Tags: c#, file-upload, http-post

I am trying to send a set of parameters and their values via http protocol in C#.

A list of parameters(specified by service provider) and their values are:

"name" -- "a name"

"type" -- "a type name"

"file_in" -- "uploaded file"

"a name" and "a type name" are string. As I did research on the Internet, the only example I found is by using addParam like:

```
request.addParam("name","a name");
request.addParam("type","a type name");
```

(Is it correct? I'm not sure about it...)

But what about "file_in"??? How can I post(upload) a file with specific parameter name "file_in" via http protocol? Could you please give me an example?

Thanks in advance for your answers :D

Comment: You should consider reviewing your old questions and accept some answers.

Comment: You could use WebClient for this purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090907/c-webclient-upload-file-to-web

Comment: this is not related to my old question. All of my old questions have already been solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check : [WebClient.UploadValues Method (Uri, NameValueCollection)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144243.aspx)